# Mysql - Union two querys with "where in" subselects

Tags: mysql, union

I have to find sku's (identifier) that are not listed in our catalog. Querys is simple

```
SELECT sku 
  FROM stock 
 WHERE sku NOT IN (SELECT sku FROM catalog)
```

but there might be also missing sku's in table sale

```
SELECT DISTINCT sku 
  FROM sale 
 WHERE sku NOT IN (SELECT sku FROM catalog)
```

I would like to get a single result from mysql, will all missing skus.
To connect these two querys with Union will not work here.
Thank you & Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using UNION

```
SELECT sku 
FROM stock 
WHERE sku NOT IN (SELECT sku FROM catalog) 

union 

SELECT sku 
FROM sale 
WHERE sku NOT IN (SELECT sku FROM catalog)
```

for obtain the distink SKU from both the queries

or

```
select  sku  
from  (
  SELECT sku FROM stock 
  union   
  SELECT  sku  FROM sale 
) t
where sku NOT IN (SELECT sku FROM catalog)
```

anyway the first should be more performant

Comment: just make sure that we guaranteed that `sku` returned from `catalog` won't be NULL; the NOT IN condition won't ever be satisfied if the subquery returns a NULL value

Comment: @spencer7593 thank you for the hint. fortunately sku cant be null in my case